# Why I dont see array's element when I do db.collection.find()?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I've got a mongo model like this:

```
attributes:[String]
```

But when I do : `db.ads.find({})`

I've got this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5571fe998f6319ed03235522"), "attributes" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

I don't see the elements in the array "attributes" even if actually the array contains this:  `["Meublé","Wi-Fi","Salle de sport"]`

I would like to be able to do a command like `db.ads.find({})` and see the element inside the array

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this in the terminal or your code?

If you are using the terminal:

Use----> `db.ads.find()`

OR---> `db.ads.find().pretty()`
to make it look good

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute in your console the following query:

```
db.ads.find({"attributes": { $not: { $size: 0 } } })
```

in order to find all documents that have non-empty `"attributes"` array.

In your case it looks like you might have many documents with this array empty and `db.ads.find()` returns a cursor which shows in your console only 20 elements in each iteration (by default), so in first iteration you may be seeing only those that have no values in `"attributes"`.

Hope this will help a little.